# Hi, I am trying to find all instances of utf8mb4_bin in my table, using REGEXP, but cannot get the right results

Tags: mysql, regex, bin, utf8mb4, collate

I can find single chars using:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%Â%' COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
```

> -- 1 result:  246.8 Â± 11.7

I have tried a dozen or more REGEXP with COLLATE utf8mb4_bin, but none return what I need.  Like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE AND HEX(column) REGEXP "^[..]*" COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
```

> -- 24356, but ALL chars, not just utf8mb4_bin

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE AND HEX(column) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin REGEXP "...";
```

> -- 24045, but ALL chars, not just utf8mb4_bin

Some of the chars I can find using the first query above, one at a time (But I need a REGEXP like query to find all, as I don't know what else exists, and I have 30M rows):  ┬╜ Ã¢â‚¬Â â€¦ ╬ô├⌐┬╝

Column collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Thanks!  Lou

Comment: Are you saying that you want to find all the characters in a column that would require the use of utf8mb4 to be properly represented?

Comment: utf8mb4_bin (I think utf8mb4 is different?  Or is _bin just the method to find utf8mb4 chars?).  I can find single utf8mb4_bin chars, but I do not know how many different ones are in the table, so I need to find all.  Essentially a REGEXP to find all of them, then I can run replace queries for each.  Thanks

Comment: `[..]*` looks for dots.  You wanted `(..)*` to look for pairs of characters; see my answer.  And the "collate" clause is probably irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

First, the "CHARACTER SET" (such as `utf8mb4`) is the encoding.  You can search for such in the data.

On top of that, the "COLLATION" (such as `utf8mb4_bin`) is how the characters are compared.  For that, you need to look in `information_schema.COLUMNS`.

To add to the confusion, `Â±` looks like "Mojibake" for `±`.  That is where the *encoding* got messed up when inserting data.  Not all "Mojibake" start with `Â`.  This gives a list of Mojibake messes from "latin1" characters:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#8_bit_encodings.  In the middle of the second table is `Â±`.

`Â±` is a rather unlikely case to home in on.  Can you find another clue?

Here is a regexp to find rows with any 8-bit chars in the column `colname`:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE HEX(colname) RLIKE '^(..)*[89A-F].';
```

If the table is huge, it will take a long time.  Also you might want to tack a `LIMIT` on the end.  (That was found in the same document.)

As for analyzing the cause for Mojibake, see [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)  And for fixing:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases

Be sure to pick the case that fits your situation.

But, but, ... If Mojibake is involved, the data may be corrupted.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE table`, `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';`  I may need some more things to help you figure out what went wrong and how to fix it.  (Unless my links suffice.)

An example of using that regexp:

```
mysql> SELECT city, country FROM `c2014`
    WHERE HEX(city) RLIKE '^(..)*[89A-F].' 
      and id%1237 = 1 and length(city) < 20
    LIMIT 7;
+------------------+---------+
| city             | country |
+------------------+---------+
| Çernoleva        | al      |
| Kashta e Bardhë  | al      |
| Sharrëdushk      | al      |
| São Tomé         | ao      |
| Teca diá Ndala   | ao      |
| Gömür            | az      |
| Balèmyouré       | bf      |
+------------------+---------+
```

Another note:  The output would be the same for either utf8mb4, utf8, or latin1.  It actually looks for "non-Ascii" characters.

Comment: Thanks Rick James.  I will investigate all you replied with and reply with results.  Will be a few days at least, other squeaky wheels...

Comment: @LouRadwan - I fixed a typo in the regexp.

Comment: Rick James, while SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE HEX(colname) RLIKE '^(..)*[8-F].'; does find chars I might want to change to entities, the chars show correct.  Like degree sign, superscripts with no sup tags, greeks like mu, etc.,   I will read thru the links you provided, and see if anything is in there to tweak the query and find others.  Thanks again.

Comment: @LouRadwan - Please provide a short list of things you want to keep and things you want to dislike.  Include the `HEX(column)` where practical.  Also `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';`

Comment: Thanks @Rick James.  I need to find chars like:  ┬╜ Ã¢â‚¬Â â€¦ ╬ô├⌐┬╝

Comment: Thanks @Rick James.  I need to find chars like:  ┬ ╜ Ã ¢ â ‚¬ Â â € ¦ ╬ ô├ ⌐ ┬ ╝  The edit you provided, is still finding superscripted chars with no sup tags, like: mm³, actual degree char, like: 100°C (not html entity &deg;), actual greek chars like µm/km (not html code for mu, &mu;).  (edit timed out so I pasted edit here)

Comment: Do you want to find `┬` but not `μ`?  Do you want _all_ accented letters, like `Á`, or only certain ones?  "Box drawing" characters are regexp "E29[45].."  It will be hard to locate one group of non-ascii characters while accepting another group.  I need to know the groupings to move forward.